# Javascript me devuelve fecha errónea

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp

En la base de datos, almaceno una fecha junto con su hora, al obtener dicha fecha, convierto el dato "TimeStamp" al tipo de dato "Date()".

Ejemplo:

```
this.dateRequired = new Date(dataObject.daterequired.timestamp * 1000);
```

Sin embargo, el javascript muestra una fecha con un día de diferencia:

Ejemplo:

```
Fecha almacenada en base de datos: 2018-03-30
Fecha mostrada por javascript: 2018-03-29
```

¿A qué podría deberse?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hay varias cosas locas que suceden con un objeto JS DATE que convierte cadenas, por ejemplo, considere la siguiente fecha:

> Nota: Los siguientes ejemplos pueden ser **UN DÍA MENOS** o no dependiendo
>   de **TU** zona horaria y hora actual.

```
new Date("2011-09-24"); // Year-Month-Day
// => Fri Sep 23 2011 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST) - UN DÍA MENOS.
```

> Sin embargo, si reorganizamos el formato de cadena a **Mes-Día-Año** ...

```
new Date("09-24-2011");
=> // Sat Sep 24 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST) - FECHA CORRECTA.
```

> Otro extraño

```
new Date("2011-09-24");
// => Fri Sep 23 2011 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST) - UN DÍA MENOS.

new Date("2011/09/24"); // change from "-" to "/".
=> // Sat Sep 24 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST) - FECHA CORRECTA.
```

> Podríamos cambiar fácilmente los guiones en la fecha "**2011-09-24**" al
>   hacer una nueva fecha

```
new Date("2011-09-24".replace(/-/g, '\/')); // => "2011/09/24".
=> // Sat Sep 24 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST) - FECHA CORRECTA.
```

> ¿Qué pasa si tenemos una cadena de fecha como "**2011-09-24T00: 00: 00**"

```
new Date("2011-09-24T00:00:00");
// => Fri Sep 23 2011 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST) - UN DÍA MENOS.
```

> Ahora cambia el **guión** a **barra diagonal** como antes; ¿que pasa?

```
new Date("2011/09/24T00:00:00");
// => Invalid Date
```

> Normalmente tengo que gestionar el formato de fecha **2011-09-24T00: 00**:
>   00, así que esto es lo que hago.

```
new Date("2011-09-24T00:00:00".replace(/-/g, '\/').replace(/T.+/, ''));
// => Sat Sep 24 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST) - FECHA CORRECTA.
```

> MAS

Si proporciona argumentos separados para el constructor de fechas, puedes obtener otros resultados útiles como se describe a continuación.

**Nota**: los argumentos pueden ser de tipo Número o Cadena. Mostraré ejemplos con valores mixtos.

> Obten el primer mes y día de un año determinado

```
new Date(2011, 0); // Normal behavior as months in this case are zero based.
=> // Sat Jan 01 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST)
```

> Obten el último mes y día de un año

```
new Date((2011 + 1), 0, 0); // The second zero roles back one day into the previous month's last day.
=> // Sat Dec 31 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST)
```

> Ejemplo de número, argumentos de cadena. Tenga en cuenta que el mes es
>   marzo porque cero meses base nuevamente.

```
new Date(2011, "02"); 
=> // Tue Mar 01 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST)
```

> Si hacemos lo mismo pero con un día de cero, obtenemos algo diferente.

```
new Date(2011, "02", 0); // again the zero roles back from March to the last day of February.
=> // Mon Feb 28 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST)
```

> Al agregar un día de cero a cualquier argumento de año y mes se
>   obtendrá el último día del mes anterior. Si continúas con números
>   negativos, puedes continuar retrocediendo otro día

```
new Date(2011, "02", -1);
=> // Sun Feb 27 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST)
```

[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556591/javascript-date-object-always-one-day-off)

Answer (score 0):

Respondo a mi propia pregunta para complementar un poquitín mas la respuesta de GDP.

GDP comentó sobre las zonas horarias, así que, al extraer el dato en UTC (Tiempo Universal Coordinado), me trae la fecha correcta que está almacenada en la base de datos.

Esto podría ser un problema puesto que en mi zona horaria son +6 horas, pero esto se podría aprovechar bastante bien para personalizar un poco la pantalla del cliente.

Muchas gracias a todos.

Answer (score 0):

converti tal cual dijo nuestro colega : "si reorganizamos el formato de cadena a Mes-Día-Año ." y toLocaleDateString() funcionó bien.

Aqui el metodo de ejemplo:

La funcion recibe "yyyy-mm-dd")

```
function conviertefecha(fecharecibidatexto)
{
        fec = fecharecibidatexto;

        anio = fec.substring(0, 4);
        mes = fec.substring(5,7);
        dia = fec.substring(8,10);

        ensamble = mes + "-" + dia + "-" + anio;
        fecha = new Date(ensamble).toLocaleDateString('es-AR');
        return fecha;
}
```

Comment: favor de no usar la zona de respuestas para hacer preguntas, comentarios o aclaraciones