# Por qué me devuelve una hora errónea con toTimeString / toLocalteTimeString en Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: javascript, date

Estoy haciendo un desarrollo de una agenda y me he encontrado un escollo que no puedo ni imaginar qué puede ser.

Estoy intentando tratar horas con el Date de javascript:

```
var date = new Date("1900/01/01 12:00");
console.log(date);
console.log(date.toTimeString());
console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString());
console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString("es-ES"));
console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString("en-US"));
```

Dependiendo de donde ejecute este bloque de código obtengo un resultado u otro.

**Mozilla Firefox**

```
Date 1900-01-01T11:00:00.000Z
12:00:00 GMT+0100
10:45:16 AM
10:45:16
10:45:16 AM
```

**Google Chrome**

```
Mon Jan 01 1900 12:00:00 GMT-0014 (hora estándar de Europa central)
12:00:00 GMT-0014 (hora estándar de Europa central)
12:00:00
12:00:00
12:00:00 PM
```

**Internet Explorer**

```
Mon Jan 01 1900 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Hora estándar romance)
12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Hora estándar romance)
‎12‎:‎00‎:‎00
‎12‎:‎00‎:‎00
‎12‎:‎00‎:‎00‎ ‎PM
```

**NodeJS**

```
1900-01-01T12:14:44.000Z
12:00:00 GMT-0014 (hora estándar de Europa central)
12:00:00
12:00:00
12:00:00 PM
```

En Mozilla Firefox me devuelve datos totalmente erróneos, mientras que en Chrome e IE me devuelve datos correctos. Además, ejecutando el mismo código en NodeJS, cuando imprimo directamente la fecha, me da un valor extraño (12:14:44), que coincide con el desplazamiento que calcula Mozilla Firefox más 30 minutos.

Además, si se pone otra hora, el desplazamiento de la hora en Mozilla sigue siendo igual. Si ponemos las 14:30 tenemos

```
Date 1900-01-01T13:30:00.000Z
14:30:00 GMT+0100
1:15:16 PM
13:15:16
1:15:16 PM
```

¿Alguien sabe qué puede ser?

Gracias de antemano

***PostData:*** [Javascript me devuelve fecha errónea](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/149033/javascript-me-devuelve-fecha-err%C3%B3nea) no resuelve mi pregunta. En mi caso no es algo común a todos los navegadores, solo a Mozilla Firefox. Además, la pregunta que se hace ahí solo está relacionada con el huso horario de Javascript.

Comment: No son fechas erróneas, lo que pasa es que la hora está basada en el _meridiano de Greenwich_. Otra cosa es que no hay que poner fechas anteriores al año _1970_, podría darte fallos.

Answer (score 0):

Según la documentación de Mozilla, el formato puede variar enormemente según la ubicación del usuario y la configuración del ordenador.

[Utiliza la propiedad options para obtener un formato más concreto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString#Using_options)
[Opciones aceptadas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString#Parameters)

En tu caso sería:

`var options = {  hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric' };
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('es-ES', options));`

Aunque ten en cuenta que al crear el objeto Date, no le estás asignando un rango UTC y no va ha hacer el calculo de GMT. 
Deberías probarlo con:

`var date = new Date(Date.UTC(1900, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0));`

> El formato por defecto depende de la plataforma, la configuración regional y la configuración del usuario.

Comment: Con opciones también lo probé y se comportaba igual. Lo que no lo probé fue indicándole que era UTC (entre otras cosas porque no quería preocuparme por el desvío horario), pero lo acabo de probar y obtengo el mismo resultado. Lo curioso es que si pregunto la hora y los minutos con date.getHours() y date.getMinutes() me devuelve 12 y 0 respectivamente. Además, he comprobado que en ordenadores fuera de mi empresa no sucede, solo son los ordenadores con mozilla (portable o instalado) que hay dentro del sistema de mi empresa.

Comment: Entonces tu caso es por la configuracion de la plataforma, un windows empresarial personalizado.